# How to use a XSD schema definition file to bulk insert records with fixed-width columns into a database?

Tags: ms-access, ssis, xsd, bcp, fixed-width

I have an XSD schema definition file that I "crafted" using Access 2007 on my flatfile with fixed-width columns/fields. Using an SSIS package, I would like to bulk insert the data from the flat file to a table in TeraData. From what I've read both here and in the MSDN library, there's a BCP utility with which I can do BULK INSERT. Only looks like it could be tricky to make changes in the XSD from Access so it could be used in BCP. Has anyone done anything similar? Truth is, there's no XML file or data because, if we were to format the flat file, it would be many more Gb of data than I'd like to deal with! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an XML Task control flow item in SSIS that may work for you.  This will perform selected operations on your XML file.  Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141055.aspx) for information.

There's also an XML Source component in the Data Flow task.  This component will load your data into the data flow where you can then export to the desired destination.  More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140277.aspx).

Comment: thanks, bobs! I'm reading it as I type and seems to be great fit if there is an XML "stream", i.e. one record is tagged-formatted and processed at a time. And then again maybe I'm just trying to make a round peg fit in a square hole... ;) in any case, just wondering if it can be done without XML formatting